# How to Edit/Update Data in Collection in C#

Tags: c#

I have a collection in my C# code

```
private ObservableCollection<UserForms> _userForms = 
    new ObservableCollection<UserForms>();

public ObservableCollection<UserForms> UserForms { get { return _userForms; } }
```

I am filling collection with 4 values

```
foreach (DataRow dr in DataTable.Rows)
{
                    UserForms.Add(new UserForms()
                    {
                        FormID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["FormID"]),
                        FormName = dr["FormName"].ToString(),
                        FromSyName = dr["FormSyName"].ToString(),
                        Visibility = false,
                        RoleAdd=false,
                        RoleEdit=false,
                        RoleDelete=false
                    });
}
```

I am filling this in `Form_Load()` event

Now I want to update

```
Visibility = true,
RoleAdd=true,
RoleEdit=true,
RoleDelete=true
```

in specified row in the collection.

Comment: _userForms.Add(new UserForms()); I dont think you are looking for so obvious answer. you need to explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to do the following:

```
UserForms[0].Visibility = true;
```

where "[0]" is the index.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ObservableCollection` is enumerable (which collections usually are) you can use a foreach loop as follows:

```
foreach(UserForms uf in UserForms)
{
    if (uf.FormID > 10)
        uf.Visibility = true;
}
```

In the above code, I change the visibility of rows which their `FormID` is higher than 10.

Comment: I want to Visibility = true; in some Rows of Collection

Comment: Well you can add an `if` statement in the `foreach` block and perform your tests.

Comment: I changed the answer to meet your new criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need filter out some items and then update them.

```
foreach(UserForms uf in UserForms.Where(i=>i.FormName == "FormName"/*put your filtering criteria here*/))
{
    uf.Visibility = true;
    // Set all needed properties here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the instance of collection.

```
_userForms.ToList().ForEach((f) => f.Visibility = true);
```

or if you know the index and want to update individual item.

```
 _userForms[index].Visibility = true;
```

or for multiple filter items

```
 var filterColl = coll.Where((c)=> c.FormName.StartsWith("A"));
 filterColl.ToList().ForEach((f) => f.Visibility = true);
```

hope this helps..

Comment: Thank u..
Please tell me How to Get RowIndex of WPF dataGrid while Checked the CheckBox of a Datagrid Column

Comment: this is not related to same question. please raise a diff question.