# How to Get RowIndex of WPF dataGrid while Checked the CheckBox of a Datagrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a wpf DataGrid with one CheckBox Column....

Then How to get RowIndex of a wpf datagrid when i Checked or Unchecked CheckBox of WPF DataGrid Column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need row index. What you really need is changing your bound item. According to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116931/how-to-edit-update-data-in-collection-in-c-sharp), you are trying to change properties of items, assigned to grid. You don't have to do that manually. If you have class

```
public class UserForm
{
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string FormName { get; set; }
    public bool Visibility { get; set; }
}
```

And you assign list of forms to `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UserForms}" />
```

or from code

```
dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGrid.ItemsSource = UserForms;
```

Then properties of bound `UserForm` object will be updated when you check/uncheck checkboxes in Visibility column of grid.

Answer (score 0):

The only way of retrieving index of row in DataGrid that I know is to traverse visual tree and count it.  Generally it is a bad idea to base logic on index of row in wpf datagrid. That is because grid is virtualized by default and this index can be misinforming.

So the way to go is to add an number to your ViewModel that is provided as data source for your row and use that in your event handler.